# Markdown editor on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I sometimes need to enter code into an issue I would like to comment on but always struggle. Indenting by four spaces is cumbersome for larger blocks, ticks work weirdly for larger blocks and I keep forgetting the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags (and they are cumbersome to write by hand).

Am I missing something or does GitHub lack a markdown editor (like the one here that lets me select a text and then click on "B" in the menu above the editor window to make the text **bold**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Github flavoured markdown is significantly better than the MD supported here on stackexchange.

However, it is true that you don't get a toolbar to help you. It is expected that you know some basics. You can use the toolbar here to help learn some basics if you like though there is a [help page linked on Github](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/). Worth learning the github extensions.

For code, the easiest approach is to use 3 backticks on their own line, optionally followed by the code language.

In addition, you can edit things in the WIKI which does have a toolbar.

Alternatively, you can use a text editor that supports MD.

Comment: Thansk, why that toolbar is not there is a mystery to me still though.